# How to dump the data base from my server into engineyard

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have my own mysql data base and have some data in it.. Now I would like to dump my database into the engineyard cloud.
I have cloud account and diployed the complete file init.. Now we need the data to run my project..
so could you please explain how to dump the db into engineyard cloud...
   Ramesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about EngineYard , But on Heroku you can issue **heroku db:push command** , which Pushes your local DB into the Cloud . I guess for EngineYard , a similar command should work .

http://blog.heroku.com/archives/2009/3/18/push_and_pull_databases_to_and_from_heroku/